# How to resolve init_db / permission denied error on Postgres cluster on Kubernetes?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I installed Crunchydata Postgres Operator on K8S by following this [link](https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgres-operator/4.6.2/installation/postgres-operator/)

I found the following link to create PG Cluster using postgres-cluster.yaml [link](https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgres-operator/latest/custom-resources/)

When I try to create the Postgres cluster using

```
kubectl create -f postgres-cluster.yml
```

it errored with the following

```
[root@ontrol01 ~]# kubectl logs -n pgo deployment.apps/hippo | more
/opt/crunchy/bin/postgres-ha/bootstrap-postgres-ha.sh: line 198: /pgdata/hippo.initial
izing: Permission denied
initdb: error: could not create directory "/pgdata/hippo": Permission denied
pg_ctl: database system initialization failed
```

I tried by adding the `"securitycontext"` to postgres-cluster.yaml (tailored output) but it does not work.  I might be wrong here

```
apiVersion: crunchydata.com/v1
kind: Pgcluster
metadata:
  annotations:
    current-primary: hippo
  labels:
    crunchy-pgha-scope: hippo
    deployment-name: hippo
    name: hippo
    pg-cluster: hippo
    pgo-version: 4.6.2
    pgouser: admin
  name: hippo
  namespace: pgo
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 0
    runAsGroup: 0
```

I am able to find similar issue in SO but I am not sure what should be added where to fix the postgres `permission denied` issue

Comment: Hi, the issue: "Permission denied" could be related to the storage configuration of your Kubernetes cluster. Could you please emphasize on that topic? How your cluster was created, is it a cloud solution? If feasible please attach the exact `YAML` manifest you've used to create this setup (postgre).

Comment: Hi! Did you solve the problem?